# Left:0; required for position?

Tags: css

I was making a horizontal dropdown menu and when positioning each dropdown menu below its item, its finicky at best.

```
#nav { float:right; }
  #nav li { display:inline;position:relative; }
    #nav li ul { display:none; }
      #nav li ul.current { position:absolute; display:block; z-index:9; left:0; }
        #nav li ul.current li { display:block; }
```

And a menu structure of

```
<ul id="nav">
  <li><a href="#">link</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">sub</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">link</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">sub</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

and some js to make it work

```
$(document).click(function(e) {
  if($(e.target).is("#nav li a")) {
    $("#nav li ul.current").removeClass("current");
    $(e.target).parent().find("ul").addClass("current");
  } else {
    $("#nav li ul.current").removeClass("current");
  }
});
```

The menu works with this code but my question is:

**Why is the left:0; required on #nav li ul.current for the sub menus to appear correctly positioned?**

Without the left:0; it works only in chrome. Opera, FF and IE8 all render the submenus at the location of the start of the #nav ul.

I thought that an absolutely positioned element went to the closest parent element with a position other than static. Which would be the #nav li not #nav.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default value for [`left` is `auto`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#position-props) and `auto` means that the browser figures out the position on its own using [various rules that you probably shouldn't care about](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#abs-non-replaced-width) unless you're writing a CSS engine. There's enough wiggle room that different browsers will come up with different results even without bugs or misinterpretations.

The position offsets are with respect to the nearest non-static ancestor (which is your `<li>`) but that doesn't mean that the offsets are zero, the `left` is still a computed value if you don't specify it and it can be a negative value.

Basically: say what you mean. You mean `left:0` so you should say that.

Answer (score -1):

Becoz when u mention position:absolute, some of the browsers understands it default setting i.e left:0px, while in other browsers where it shows absurd results it might not be understanding the default settings.

I think this should be the reason...